# Ordering results by the sum of each row

Tags: mysql, database, sum

The query below orders the results by date not my the sum of the `count1, count2, count3, count4`.

I've been messing with this for a while now and can't seem to get anywhere with it.

```
SELECT date, (count1 + count2 + count3 + count4) AS total
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 0,100;
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: in the TOTAL value giving you the correct sum like you are expecting? Please show your table definition using `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` to help providing the correct answer. I would like to know the type of the column and weather they are null-able or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your table definition but give this a try

```
SELECT date, ( IFNULL(Count1,0) + IFNULL(Count2,0) + IFNULL(Count3,0) + IFNULL(Count4,0)) as TOTAL
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY ( IFNULL(Count1,0) + IFNULL(Count2,0) + IFNULL(Count3,0) + IFNULL(Count4,0)) DESC
LIMIT 0,100;
```

**EDITED**

The problem is that NULL is not a value and when you try to add NULL to a number you will always get NULL.

To test this you can do this

```
SELECT 1 + null;  -- this will return NULL
```

You could make your columns not null-able and make the default value 0 then you won't have to check for NULL anymore.

Comment: That actually fixed it, I'm just very confused why the null values threw everything off.  Why did that work and how did you know?

Comment: That's why I suggested to show your table definition. I edited my answer to explain the issue. If you are happy with the answer please accept it. thank you :)